# How to use custom url instead of Maven Central for sourcing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Say I am hosting a JAR file on a url like:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/async-java/jars/master/x.jar

How can I tell Maven to use this url instead of the default (to Maven Central)?

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.my</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-deps</artifactId>
     <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I assume somewhere in one of those xml configs we can tell Maven to use the above URL for it? Anybody know the right way to do this?

*If it wasn't clear - I don't want to host an entire Maven Repository - I just want to serve a .jar file.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have different URLs for jars -- but these URLs need to host Maven repositories.

The standard way to add further repositories (in addition to the implicitly present MavenCentral) is to add them to the `settings.xml`. It is also possible to add them to the POM itself.

A Maven repositories does not have to be a Nexus/Artifactory. It is important, though, that the URL reflects groupId, artifactId, version etc. in the standard manner.

Comment: thanks. this is not convenient for end-users tho if I am trying to distribute software that is hosted somewhere other than maven central, b/c this would expect users to modify their settings.xml instead of just copying the xml to their pom.xml

Comment: Most of the (open source) libraries are indeed on MavenCentral. You can also publish your jar there.

Comment: Publishing to maven central is a bit tricky and the turn-around is slower, just trying to host it myself in the off chance it's useful at some point. If you can add a little more info how the xml config would look, I will prob accept your answer thx

Comment: This is outlined in https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: Yeah but a URL to a repository is not the same as URL to a jar file is it. I would like to be able to have a URL to a jar file, without hosting an entire maven repository. I thought that was clear enough given the OP? I will add that to the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned in my answer that this cannot be done. You need to host a Maven repository if you want to distribute a jar. There are different ways to host a Maven repository. Besides the "standard" ways of using Nexus or Artifactory, you can also use a plain web server and make sure your jar lies in a directory structure that coincides with the structure in the local repository.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my pom.xml to reference a shared maven repository that is not maven central.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my.maven.repository</id>
        <url>https://mymavenrepo.com/jars/location</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```